# Onboard intel graphics for Gigabyte B560M DS3H AC mother board not working in Ubuntu 20.04 or 20.10 getting only 1024X768 resolution

Tags: 20.04, graphics, intel

[image: System details]

Onboard intel graphics for Gigabyte B560M DS3H AC mother board not working in Ubuntu 20.04 or 20.10 getting 0nly 1024X768 resolution. I am using intel core i7 11 gen 11700k processor, 32 gb ddr4 ram and onboard wifi and bluetooth. Except display drivers remaining all working. For Graphics issue followed all the solutions that I could see online. Nothing worked. Not able to play mp4 videos in browser. After doing 1 week of research, multiple installations found that Intel is providing UHD 750 graphics which need kernel 5.9 or higher. Also found that Intel did not release drivers for these graphics as of now.

```
$> sudo lshw -c video giving below output:

  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:50000000-50ffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

$> glxinfo -B giving below output: 

name of display: :1
display: :1  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 20.2.6
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 31908MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Comment: Try the upcoming 21.04, just in case...

Answer (score 1):

My situation is similar to yours. I solved this problem by installing `linux-oem-20.04b`.

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04b
```

See [UnclaImed display in ubuntu 21.04 with Rocket Lake](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334227/unclaimed-display-in-ubuntu-21-04-with-rocket-lake).